# Create SWC using Flash Builder 4

Tags: flash, ant, flash-builder, swc

I need to embed my graphic assets into a swc.

I created a diretrory structure reflecting my packages

```
com
    example
        Foo.png
```

I need to create a swc containing a com.example.Foo class (subclass of DisplayObject)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Flex Library" project, it will genere a swc automagically.

Comment: I need an swc created by a .png, I'm creating an ant task to do so.